# How to get data from local JSON file in swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, tableview

I want to get data from local JSON file. It's look like:

```
[
[
{
  "link": "link1",
  "answers": [
    "answer1",
    "answer2",
    "answer3",
    "answer4",
    "answer5"
  ],
  "questions": "question1"
},
{
  "link": "link2",
  "answers": [
    "answer1",
    "answer2",
    "answer3",
    "answer4",
    "answer5"
  ],
  "questions": "question2"
}
]
]
```

How can I take separately each element?
And how can I take separately each answer?
I want to use answers in table view.
indexPath.row[1] = answer1
indexPath.row[2] = answer2...

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "info", withExtension: "json")!
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)
        print(json)

        //let current = json["title"] as! [String: [String:Any]]

        //for (key, currency) in current {
            //let quest = currency["title"] as! String
            //let img = currency["image"] as! String
            //let ans = currency["answers"] as! [String]
        //}
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use the Codable protocol if you are using Swift 4. Parsing JSON has been discussed on [here many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift+json)

Comment: You are almost there.  Give the deserialized JSON data to an array of an array of a dictionary.

Comment: @Scriptable Actually, it's not terribly a bad idea to use a JSON file to store data.  I occasionally use a JSON and a Info.plist file to store game level data.

Comment: @ElTomato I didn't mention anything about storing data using a JSON file. just suggested using Codable (which you can use with a file) and advised there are loads of Q&As on here already regarding this topic so theres likely already an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take care of the `JSON` structure to get the correct values. See the below snippet to see how you can reach your questions in `JSON`.

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "txt")!
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [[[String: Any]]]

        if let question1 = json.first?[0] {
            print( question1["link"] as! String)
        }

        if let question2 = json.first?[1] {
            print( question2["link"] as! String)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

So now, you know how to reach the actual data. You should create some `Question` class. Then you should retain a list of questions parsed from the file and use that list for your `TableView`.

Comment: you are the best;)

Comment: @NoName Glad it helped!

Comment: But if I want to display each answer separately?
for i in json?.first?[1]["answers"] as! [String] {
                    print(i)
                }